# How to test a service with no entrypoint for data test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm learning how to use the Nunit.

I have an interface called "IMenuService". This interface has one method that given the menuType, it's return the list of menuItem requested.

Actually I have create a simple implementation called "StaticMenuService" that contains two static menu: admin / user.
StaticMenuService not required any Repository because it's data are harcoded, so it's constructor has no parameters.

I would to test "GetMenu(MenuType type)" methods using two test lists that rappresent the admin / menu, but I don't know how to pass these test list since StaticMenuService has not data entrypoint.

What I think is to modify "StaticMenuService" constructor adding two parameters (UserMenu, AdminMenu) but in that case I modify a real class only for
create a test and I think it's wrong, isn't it?

How can I use my fake data to implement tests?

This is what i started

```
public class MenuServiceTest
    {

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            List<MenuContainerItem> AdminMenuContainer;
            List<MenuContainerItem> UserMenuContainer;

            MenuPageItem adminPageTest1 = new MenuPageItem()
            {
                Id = "TEST_ADMIN_PAGE_1",
                PageName = "admin test 1",
                Url = "/admin/test1"
            };
            MenuPageItem adminPageTest2 = new MenuPageItem()
            {
                Id = "TEST_ADMIN_PAGE_2",
                PageName = "admin test 2",
                Url = "/admin/test2"
            };

            MenuContainerItem AdminBasePagesTest = new MenuContainerItem()
            {
                Id = "ADMIN_CONTAINER_TEST",
                Icon = "preferences",
                ContainerName = "container test",
                Pages = new List<MenuPageItem>() { adminPageTest1 , adminPageTest2}
            };

            AdminMenuContainerTest = new List<MenuContainerItem>() { AdminBasePagesTest };
            UserMenuContainerTest = new List<MenuContainerItem>();


        }

        [TestCase(MenuType.ADMIN)]
        [TestCase(MenuType.USER)]
        public void IMenuServiceReturnsAlwaysAList(MenuType type)
        {
            //var mockData = new Mock<>
            //how can I pass AdminMenuContainerTest and UserMenuContainerTest to an instance of StaticMenuService?
        }
    }
```

DataModels

```cs
public class MenuPageItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}


public class MenuContainerItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public IList<MenuPageItem> Pages { get; set; }
}

public enum MenuType
{
    ADMIN = 0,
    USER = 1
}
```

Interfaces

```cs
public interface IMenuService
{
   IList<MenuContainerItem> GetMenu(MenuType type);
}
```

StaticMenuService

```
public class StaticMenuService : IMenuService
    {
        private List<MenuContainerItem> AdminMenuContainer;
        private List<MenuContainerItem> UserMenuContainer;

        public StaticMenuService()
        {
            MenuPageItem adminPageUsers = new MenuPageItem() {
                Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_1",
                PageName = "gestione utenti",
                Url = "/admin/users"
            };
            MenuPageItem adminPageRoles = new MenuPageItem() {
                Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_2",
                PageName = "gestione ruoli",
                Url = "/admin/roles"
            };
            MenuPageItem adminPageUserRoles = new MenuPageItem() {
                Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_3",
                PageName = "gestione utenti - ruoli",
                Url = "/admin/userRoles"
            };

            MenuContainerItem AdminBaseManagerPages = new MenuContainerItem() {
                Id = "ADMIN_CONTAINER",
                Icon = "preferences",
                ContainerName = "Gestione",
                Pages = new List<MenuPageItem>() { adminPageUsers, adminPageRoles, adminPageUserRoles }
            };

            AdminMenuContainer = new List<MenuContainerItem>() { AdminBaseManagerPages };

            UserMenuContainer = new List<MenuContainerItem>();
        }

        public IList<MenuContainerItem> GetMenu(MenuType type)
        {
            if(type == MenuType.ADMIN)
            {
                return AdminMenuContainer.AsReadOnly();
            } 

            if(type == MenuType.USER)
            {
                return UserMenuContainer.AsReadOnly();
            }

            return new List<MenuContainerItem>().AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
```

Any help, advice or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Code has tight coupling, making it difficult to test in isolation. You would need to invert the control of creating the data in order to be able to use fake data in an isolated test

Comment: thanks to reply @Nkosi! So you suggest to create a repository that return the menu items? In that case I can mok the repository during the test.. Is this your suggestion?

Comment: does not necessarily/technically have to be a repository, but you would need an external dependency or expose a member that would allow you to manipulate/change data for testing/

Answer (score 2):

> What I think is to modify "StaticMenuService" constructor adding two parameters (UserMenu, AdminMenu) but in that case I modify a real class only for create a test and I think it's wrong, isn't it?

I don't think there is anything wrong with this idea, I would even argue that its right! Your menu will be much cleaner once menu items are passed in rather than constructed internally. You also have the freedom to change menu items as much as possible without needing to modify your menu.

```
public class StaticMenuService : IMenuService
{
    private List<MenuContainerItem> AdminMenuContainer;
    private List<MenuContainerItem> UserMenuContainer;

    public StaticMenuService(List<MenuContainerItem> adminMenus, List<MenuContainerItem> userMenus)
    {
        AdminMenuContainer = adminMenus;
        UserMenuContainer = userMenus;
    }

    public IList<MenuContainerItem> GetMenu(MenuType type)
    {
        if(type == MenuType.ADMIN)
        {
            return AdminMenuContainer.AsReadOnly();
        } 

        if(type == MenuType.USER)
        {
            return UserMenuContainer.AsReadOnly();
        }

        return new List<MenuContainerItem>().AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Testing becomes super simple, just pass your fake instances in the constructor. As for what to do with the hard-coded menus that we stripped out, put them in some external class responsible for defining menus for roles. There are a million ways to do this, here is an example:

```
public class AdminMenus 
{

    public static implicit operator List<MenuContainerItem> (AdminMenus menus) 
    {
        MenuPageItem adminPageUsers = new MenuPageItem() {
            Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_1",
            PageName = "gestione utenti",
            Url = "/admin/users"
        };
        MenuPageItem adminPageRoles = new MenuPageItem() {
            Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_2",
            PageName = "gestione ruoli",
            Url = "/admin/roles"
        };
        MenuPageItem adminPageUserRoles = new MenuPageItem() {
            Id = "ADMIN_PAGE_3",
            PageName = "gestione utenti - ruoli",
            Url = "/admin/userRoles"
        };

        MenuContainerItem AdminBaseManagerPages = new MenuContainerItem() {
            Id = "ADMIN_CONTAINER",
            Icon = "preferences",
            ContainerName = "Gestione",
            Pages = new List<MenuPageItem>() { adminPageUsers, adminPageRoles, adminPageUserRoles }
        };

        return new List<MenuContainerItem>() { AdminBaseManagerPages };
    }

} 

public class UserMenus 
{
    public static implicit operator List<MenuContainerItem> (UserMenus menus) 
    {
        return new List<MenuContainerItem>();
    }
}
```

Now you could call it like this:

```
var menuService = new StaticMenuService(new AdminMenus(), new UserMenus());
```

---

Looking at what `StaticMenuService` has become, you could replace the service with a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) or some [lookup object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8) that uses `MenuType` as a key and returns a list of menu container items. This would remove the need for the if statements which can become a nightmare to maintain down the line.

Comment: Thanks you CaTs! I thought it was wrong to change the code based on unit test, but maybe this is what TDD (or testing) wants, isn't it?

Based on the fact that this is a simple exercise to learn how to test and how to use the TDD paradigm.. I think that another solution is to create a repository. In that case I can create multiple implementations of "IMenuService" for each kind of data source: static (like this example), json, sqlLite, SQLServer and much more, right?

Comment: I can't remember where I read it but I like the quote that with TDD, the test is the first client of your system. If it's hard to test then it's probably hard to use! And I think your spot on with the repo idea, much better than my example.

Comment: I apprecied your support. As I wrote in the question: I'm learning how to test with NUnit and how to use TDD

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're getting at, I believe you might benefit from creating an [Abstract Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members) instead of an Interface for menu service.

This way, you can instantiate the type of menu service that you are attempting to pass in to your unit tests.

For example:

```
public abstract class MenuService
{
    public MenuService(List<MenuContainerItem>() container)
    {
        // do shared container setup 
    }
}

public class AdminMenuService : MenuService
{
    public AdminMenuService(List<MenuContainerItem>() container) : base(container)
    {
    }
}
```

And then, in your unit test, you could do something like this:

```
var adminMenuService = new AdminMenuService()
var userMenuService = new UserMenuService()

[TestCase(adminMenuService)]
[TestCase(userMenuService)]
public void IMenuServiceReturnsAlwaysAList(MenuService menuService)
{
    menuService.getMenu() // test what you expect to happen in all MenuServices
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I like your solution but this time I think that the solution much closer to my problem is to create an external class that is responsible to sending me the requested data